# Unable to exec() in gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, exec

I want to be able to run this command

```
exec('devtool bin/www --watch -s');
```

inside of a gulp task

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
    , exec = require('child_process').exec
    , nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');

gulp.task('startCmd', function (cb) {
        console.info('running'); //running (aka it runs)
        exec('devtool '+ __dirname +'../../bin/www --watch -s');
});
```

So why does this cmd not run?

Windows 10/Ubuntu 16.5

Comment: Did you try adding a forward slash *after* concatenating `__dirname`? It does not already contain one at the end.

Comment: No luck :( `exec('devtool '+ __dirname +'/../../bin/www --watch -s');` The problem is I'm not even sure how to test that it is executing at all.

Comment: Did you try adding [a callback](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)? It will get called when the process exits.